# How can I get multiple lines of frame dots in beamer navigation?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, navigation, mini-frames

I'm writing a presentation using the `Darmstadt` theme which uses the `smoothbars` outer theme which is itself just a mild variation of `miniframes`.

In a couple of my sections, I have so many frames that the dots in the navigation bar (which I very much like) "overflow" horizontally and appear under the next section's header.

I have seen some presentations where the dots appear on a second line once they hit the width of the text for the section header.  How can I do this?

Comment: I have a solution that is working only with `miniframes` and not with `smoothbars`, the difference is that `miniframes` have no shading. Are you interested in that?

Answer (score 5):

`beamer` can't automatically wrap the mini frames into a new line if they don't fit into a single one. Instead, a new line is started for *each subsection* when using with the `miniframes` theme:

[image: headline produced by miniframes, with three lines of mini frames]

Unfortunately this doesn't work for the `Darmstadt` theme you are using. The reason for this is that `Darmstadt` loads the outer theme `smoothbars`, which is very similar to the `miniframes` theme, but installs smooth shaded transitions between the header and the content. However, it also uses beamer's `compress` option to get all the mini frames into a single line, so using multiple subsections doesn't work here. Removing this option is not a good idea, though, because the shading is hard-coded into the theme, so the header can't change its height automatically and will overflow if you use multiple lines for the mini frames:

[image: headline produced by smoothbars, with overflowing mini frames]

So the only thing you can do is to replace the `smoothbars` outer theme with `miniframes` (producing the headline shown in the first image):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\makeatletter
  \beamer@compressfalse
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\frame{}
\end{document}
```

Like this, you can wrap the mini frames into several lines by using multiple subsections, as shown in the example code.