# Problem with smoothbars in beamer package

Tags: beamer, header-footer, presentations, navigation, mini-frames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get multiple lines of frame dots in beamer navigation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35796/how-can-i-get-multiple-lines-of-frame-dots-in-beamer-navigation)

I'm using `beamer` package for a presentation using `smoothbars` to display an index in the top.

The problem is that the presentation is rather big and one section has a lot of frames. So there is not enough space to put all dots and it's not displaying right for the last sections.

I've attached an image and a MWE showing the problem. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}  %< - For lots of frames
\usepackage{lmodern} %<- For suppresion some of the warnings
\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
        \useoutertheme{shadow}
        \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
}
\begin{document}              
        \section{section 1}
                \subsection{sub1}
\foreach \x in {1,...,30}{\begin{frame}\end{frame}}

        \section{section 2}
                \subsection{sub2}
\foreach \x in {1,...,45}{\begin{frame}\end{frame}}

        \section{section 3}
                \subsection{sub3}
                        \begin{frame}\end{frame}

        \section{section 4}
                \subsection{sub4}
                        \begin{frame}\end{frame}

        \section{section 5}
                \subsection{sub5}
                        \begin{frame}\end{frame}
                        \begin{frame}\end{frame}
                        \begin{frame}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you use "parts"? This way the top bar is reset at the beginning of each new part. Or maybe you have simply to many slides.

Comment: @pluton unfortunately I can't reduce the number of slides, The presentation will have at least 60 of them...

Comment: If there is a way to break the dots in 2 lines, I think it would solve the problem and not let the other sections go off the slide

Comment: @Bruno Bruck if you use `\subsection` that's pretty much the default behavior of the `miniframe` style. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35796/how-can-i-get-multiple-lines-of-frame-dots-in-beamer-navigation

Comment: I posted it as an answer then so that your question can me marked as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `\subsection`, the default behaviour of the `miniframes` style, is such that the bullets will be nicely organized. See [How can I get multiple lines of frame dots in beamer navigation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35796/how-can-i-get-multiple-lines-of-frame-dots-in-beamer-navigation)