How to wrap the miniframes in beamer automatically?
I have consulted the links that scale the miniframe or just hide the other section.
With a slide document with many frames, the choices are worked:

change the scale of miniframe
hide ALL the miniframes in headline
hide other section's miniframes

My MWE is as follows:
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \int_step_inline:nn {4}{
        \section{FrameTitle}
        \int_step_inline:nn {30}{
        \begin{frame}
            \lipsum[##1]
        \end{frame}
        }
    }
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


However, what I want is that is there exists any configuration to wrap the bullet of miniframes automatically. Detailedly,say that as if I have M sections and N frames in each section, the headlines box could be divided into M subparts in average, and calculate the natural width(like \linewidth/M) of each subparts(such that the natural space contains 15 bullets' space),then if that N is larger than 15, I hope the headline of the beamer can wrap the bullets to the next line automtically.
In a word, my ideal result is with loooooooong frames in many sections shown as below:


[New Problem Here]
After consulting the elegant solution provided by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I can get the multiple miniframes with the following result, however, I found that the Last Section's miniframe width is a bit narrow, is there good solution to automatically modify its location?
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{Berlin}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35796/how-can-i-get-multiple-lines-of-frame-dots-in-beamer-navigation
\makeatletter
  \beamer@compressfalse
\makeatother

\newcounter{frameinsection}
\AtBeginSection{
  \setcounter{frameinsection}{0}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \let\intmodnn\int_mod:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{
  \addtocounter{frameinsection}{1}
  \ifnum \intmodnn{\theframeinsection}{10} = 1
    \subsection{}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn {3}{
    \section{FrameTitle}
    \int_step_inline:nn {45}{
    \begin{frame}
      123
    \end{frame}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}



does this display really provide useful information to your audience?

choose a longer title for the last section (could be spaces) or choose a value smaller than 15 for wrapping.

@cfr Yes, your comment is right for a presentation, the slides should be focused on the key which shouln't be too long, but the case I make is just to show the problem. Maybe? It just like a kid to show off his new toys to test it with many frames(un-hmm). thanks to yr remind!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Okay, 15 is actually to much....

@Explorer To go with the picture you painted: miniframes are the annoying noise-maker toys children (presenter) love, but whose parents (audience) will hate you for.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, I know that I should't and there is less case to use soooooo many slides. MWE below is just produced to show the small drawbacks, I will NOT do that, thanks u!

To me your EDIT sounds like a follow-up question. If so, I suggest to post it as a new one, with a link to this one.
